# How do I read a text file into array of lines and display it using PHP?

Tags: php, io

I have text file that looks like this:

```
1 1 1 1

1 2 3 5

4 4 5 5
```

I want to read this text file into array of lines and display it.  Can anyone help me do this?

Answer (score 2):

This should get you going: [php function file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

Comment: I use to use this function and I like. but it can kill you server if the file is too big since this function try to load all the file on memory, depending on the file size you need to use fopen and move the cursor

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$cont = file_get_contents("data.txt");
$lines = explode("\n",$cont); // $lines is now an array containing each line

// do something with data here

?>
```

make sure you use the correct line endings however as Windows uses `\r\n` and UNIX uses `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use fopen(), fgets(). see [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

eg

```
$f=fopen("file","r");
if($f){
    while (!feof($f)) {
        $line = fgets($f, 4096);
        print $line;
    }
    fclose($f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to do something like this:

```
<?

$filename = "somefile.txt";
$arr = file($filename);
foreach($arr as $line){
    print $line . "<br />";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is working for me.

```
 $array = explode("\n", file_get_contents('file.txt'));
```